# MS Visual Studio Project Dependencies disabled

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio

I have a problem with MS Visual c++ 2002 (first .net = version 7).

When I go into 'Project Dependencies' (Build Order) all of the flags (no matter which project I select) are disabled - not greyed like 'is already dependent', but locked for changes.

This was working fine, for as long as I remember, but I need to add a DLL to my project and can't get the build order working because of this issue.

Has anyone had a similar problem? Or know where I can find a config file to write it manually?

> **Edit:**
>
> This problem occurs in ALL of my solutions, even older ones that haven't been changed in years.

Comment: Yet the projects are otherwise enabled? I would check that they are enabled in the buld

Comment: I've managed to work around the issue by going into Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies and adding to *.lib then manually building the DLLs that out of order. Later on I might try to reinstall the virtual machine...

Comment: Yes they are enabled. Everything is OK there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to fix this in the program, but I found a way to set it up manually, if anyone else has this issue...

If you open the *.sln (solution) file into a text editor:
- At the top of the file you will see all of your projects in this format:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 7.00
Project("{XXXXXXXX-0000-XXXX-0000-SOLUTIONGUID}") = "SLN_NAME", "_path_\proj_name_1.vcproj", "{00000000-XXXX-0000-GUID-PROJECT_0001}"
EndProject
Project("{XXXXXXXX-0000-XXXX-0000-SOLUTIONGUID}") = "SLN_NAME", "_path_\proj_name_2.vcproj", "{00000000-XXXX-0000-GUID-PROJECT_0002}"
EndProject
Project("{XXXXXXXX-0000-XXXX-0000-SOLUTIONGUID}") = "SLN_NAME", "_path_\proj_name_3.vcproj", "{00000000-XXXX-0000-GUID-PROJECT_0003}"
EndProject
```

Further down you will see:

```
GlobalSection(ProjectDependencies) = postSolution
    {00000000-XXXX-0000-GUID-PROJECT_0001}.0 = {00000000-XXXX-0000-GUID-PROJECT_0002}
    {00000000-XXXX-0000-GUID-PROJECT_0001}.1 = {00000000-XXXX-0000-GUID-PROJECT_0003}
EndGlobalSection
```

Follow the Format and add the dependencies manually

- **Be sure to close the solution and back-up first**